# Poetry & Tox: How to pass arguments to commands via Tox when running in Poetry

Tags: python-poetry, tox

When I try to pass an argument to a command via Tox v4.2.6 within Poetry it is failing to recognise `--` as a separator.

Command:

```
poetry run tox -- \$username:\$password
```

Tox error:

```
tox: error: unrecognized arguments: $username:$password

hint: if you tried to pass arguments to a command use -- to separate them from tox ones
```

When I run the same Tox command outside of Poetry it works as expected (`tox -- \$username:\$password`)

Does anyone know what I am missing?

my `tox.ini` is:

```
[tox]
envlist = py39,lint,bandit
isolated_build = True
toxworkdir = {toxinidir}/build/tox

[base]
setenv =
    PIP_INDEX_URL = 
https://{posargs}@blah.artifactory.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-blah-prod-virtual/simple

[testenv]
setenv =
    {[base]setenv}
deps =
    pytest
    pyyaml
commands = pytest --junitxml=junit-{envname}.xml
```

Thanks!

Comment: `--` is eaten by `poetry` so it runs `tox \$username:\$password`. To pass additional `--` try `poetry run tox -- -- \$username:\$password`

Comment: Excellent, thanks, that seems to have sorted it! Do you want to add that as an answer so I can give it a tick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--` is eaten by poetry so it runs `tox \$username:\$password`. To pass additional `--` execute

```bash
poetry run tox -- -- \$username:\$password
```